# Problems using teamcity command line to perform ssh remote login

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, ssh, qnx, teamcity-5.1

I was wondering if anyone has tried using teamcity's command line builder to perform ssh remote login.

Right now, I would like to automate some testing on a QNX neutrino OS which is currently unsupported by teamcity. As a work around, I setup a ssh server on the target qnx machine so i could ssh and sftp the executables in.

Firstly, the source are compiled on Windows XP using qnx's compiler (based on g++). Followed by sftp-ing the executables into qnx neutrino.
Next, using ssh, script the login to remotely start the test apps and send the results back to the remote agent for publishing.

The batch script I created works well standalone, however, after hooking it up on the remote agent, it fails to login ssh and hangs indefinitely at the following command:
ssh -l   "./.sh"

Notes:
I have added the remote agent's RSA public key in the QNX .ssh/authorized keys file, automatic login is working.
Is there a need to add the teamcity server's RSA public key in too?

Anyone has any idea on this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a few weird problems with key-based SSH logins on QNX related to file permissions for the keys in .ssh. and permissions of parent folders (/home/username and /root).

Add

```
LogLevel DEBUG3
```

to /etc/openssh/sshd_config, make sure syslog is configured and is logging sshd output, restart sshd and try again - it will most likely complain about something.

Also, ssh -l "./.sh" makes no sense - -l is used to specify the user name, something is off there.